# Facebook's webhook Application creation failing due to "unable to verify provided URL"

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can't create Webhook applicaion on Facebook because of error "unable to verify provided URL"

[image]

1. The url given for callback is working fine from browser with https port 443
2. The Servlet code to recieve the post call from webhook as below

   ```
       protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            System.out.println("**************Entering Callback Servlet**************************");
               Map<String, String[]> parametersMap = request.getParameterMap();
               if (parametersMap.size() > 0) {
                   if (request.getParameter("hub.mode").equals("streamInit")) {
                       System.out.println("Verify Token: " + request.getParameter("hub.verify_token"));
                       System.out.println("Challenge number:" + request.getParameter("hub.challenge"));
                       String responseToClient = request.getParameter("hub.challenge");
                       response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                       response.getWriter().write(responseToClient);
                       response.getWriter().flush();
                       response.getWriter().close();           
                       response.getWriter().append("Fetch-Mode").append(request.getParameter("hub.mode"));
                       response.getWriter().append("App Verify Token:").append(request.getParameter("hub.verify_token"));
                       response.getWriter().append("App Challenge No").append(request.getParameter("hub.challenge"));
                       System.out.println("**************Callback Successful**************************");
                      }

                   //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
                   }else{
                       System.out.println("**************Not an Facebook POST**************************");
                   }
                  System.out.println("**************Exiting Callback Servlet**************************");


           }



   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
               doGet(request, response);
           }
   ```

Need help on what I'm missing here.

Comment: You are not really using IP `0.0.0.0` here though, are you? You can not use a local IP address for this, it must be a publicly reachable URL. (And I am not sure if an IP address works at all – in most cases, Facebook wants URLs that have a host name.)

Comment: No.I'm not. using 0.0.0.0. I have a public URL and its reachable. but I'm not having a signed SSL certificate as markus said. I'm on a dead end now :)

Comment: Yes, that’s true, you need to provide an HTTPS URL nowadays. A cheap and easy way to get a valid SSL certificate is https://letsencrypt.org/, but it requires that your server plays along (lets you use its client that deals with the domain verification.) If that is not an option, https://www.startssl.com/ provides free certificates for individuals as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook wants to be pointed to the exact file (eg.: callback.php) you could workaround this with mod rewrite. Just to mention it, the https:// certificate must be valid and signed by a public authority (e.g.: comodo).

Comment: ok. I dont have a signed SSL cert. is there any way i can real-time feeds other than webhook?

Comment: @KarthickRadhakrishnan no. but you can get a signed sll cert for about 8$ a jear. The cheapest I found is at [namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/comodo/positivessl.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://ngrok.com/ to send https Webhooks to your localhost dev server.

`if (request.getParameter("hub.mode").equals("streamInit"))`

to

`if (request.getParameter("hub.mode").equals("subscribe"))`

I did not need to point it at an exact file.